# PowerShell script to compare latest version number of master and web DB in sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell-extensions

Can Anyone help writing a PS script to get the item list where the latest version on web db is different than master

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post an example of your code attempt(s)?

Comment: I am able to get all the child items and loop through the items to get the web and master db version of the file. I am not able to get the version of individual items.

Comment: The objects have a property called Version.

Comment: @MichaelWest : I got it while debugging, I am very new to power-shell. Thanks for your help !!  I have prepared the script !

Comment: @user1621791 if you have an answer, please post it as an answer here so that others may benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

As Richard Seal mentioned, the answer may benefit others in future who refer this question.

```
$masterdatabase = "master"
$webdatabase = "web"
$root = Get-Item -Path (@{$true="$($masterdatabase):\content\home"; $false="$($masterdatabase):\content"}[(Test-Path -Path "$($masterdatabase):\content\home")])


$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="root"; Title="Choose the report root"; Tooltip="Only items from this root will be returned."; }
            )
    Title = "comparison Report"
    Description = "Choose the criteria for the report."
    Width = 550
    Height = 300
    ShowHints = $true
    Icon = [regex]::Replace($PSScript.Appearance.Icon, "Office", "OfficeWhite", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
}

$result = Read-Variable @props

if($result -eq "cancel") {
    exit
}

filter Where-comparereport {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$item
    )

    if ($item) {
        $masteritem = $item.Versions.GetLatestVersion().Statistics.Revision

        $webitem = [Sitecore.Data.Database]::GetDatabase($webdatabase).GetItem($item.Id)
        if($webitem){

        $webitemnumber = $webitem.Versions.GetLatestVersion().Statistics.Revision

        if (!$masteritem.Equals($webitemnumber)) {
            $item
        }
        }
    }
}

$items = @($root) + @(($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item)) | Where-comparereport

if($items.Count -eq 0) {
    Show-Alert "There are no content items that is different from web and master database"
} else {
    $props = @{
        Title = "Item versions difference Report"
        InfoTitle = "Items that the latest version on web db is different than master"
        InfoDescription = "Items that the latest version on web db is different than master"
        PageSize = 25
    }

    $items |
        Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label="Icon"; Expression={$_.__Icon} },
            @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} },
            @{Label="Updated"; Expression={$_.__Updated} },
            @{Label="Updated by"; Expression={$_."__Updated by"} },
            @{Label="Created"; Expression={$_.__Created} },
            @{Label="Created by"; Expression={$_."__Created by"} },
            @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.ItemPath} }
}

Close-Window
```

Comment: Could someone explain to me what line 3 is doing, please?

Comment: Ok it checks if sitecore/content/Home path exists, if so it uses that as the root, if not, it uses sitecore/content as the root.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a button in the ribbon to check items that are different, and to do so I've made a little change to the very first line, 
now I can click on any item and have a report of all children that needs to be published

```
$currentItemPath = get-location
$masterdatabase = "master"
$webdatabase = "web"
$root = Get-Item -Path (@{$true="$currentItemPath"; $false="$($masterdatabase):\content"}
[(Test-Path -Path "$currentItemPath")])
```